# Size of string variable

Tags: c++, string, size

I've got 2 questions:

1. How much RAM does string variable use? Is it 28 bytes and no matter how many chars it consists of?
2. What if length of such string is more than 28 chars? Does it take 2x more (56 bytes) or not?

Comment: Note that `sizeof()` is a compile time constant.

Answer (score 3):

> How much RAM does string variable use?

C++ has no concept of RAM. It knows only about static memory, automatic memory, and dynamic memory. How those are implemented depend on the particular details of the OS and compiler.

A `string` object is typically stored in automatic memory (such as on a thread's stack), unless you explicitly allocate it in dynamic memory (such as on a heap) via the `new` operator. If the `string` is a member of a class/struct that is allocated with `new`, but itself is not `new`'ed, then it is in automatic memory that just happens to be backed by dynamic memory.

> Is it 28 bytes and no matter how many chars it consists of?

In any case, `sizeof(string)` number of bytes are allocated, which may or may not be 28 bytes, depending on the `string`'s particular implementation. But yes, the size of a `string` object is fixed at compile-time and does not change at runtime, regardless of how many characters are stored inside the string.

> What if length of such string is more than 28 chars? Does it take 2x more (56 bytes) or not?

A `string`'s character data is usually allocated in dynamic memory (unless the length is small and the `string` implements "Short String Optimization"). The allocated size will always be the `string`'s `capacity` (plus a little overhead from the `string`'s `allocator`). But how much `capacity` is used is up to the `string`'s particular implementation to decide. And while the `capacity` can grow as characters are added, how much it grows at a time is determined by the implementation.